# How to create word cloud of different group in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, word-cloud

I have below data, and I am trying to create wordcloud for each and every "person" i.e. 1,2,3. I am using below code for wordcloud creation,but I am not sure how to create word cloud for each group.
Note: I am new to python please provide explanation along with reference if needed.

**Dataset:**

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Person':['1', '1','1','2','2','2','2','3','3'],'Response':['I like to eat','You have nice day','My name is ','I like to eat','You have nice day','My name is','This is it','I like to eat','You have nice day'],
       }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

**Code for Wordcloud**

```
from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
stopwords = set(STOPWORDS)

def show_wordcloud(data, title = None):
    wordcloud = WordCloud(
        background_color='white',
        stopwords=stopwords,
        max_words=200,
        max_font_size=40, 
        scale=3,
        random_state=1 # chosen at random by flipping a coin; it was heads
    ).generate(str(data))

    fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(12, 12))
    plt.axis('off')
    if title: 
        fig.suptitle(title, fontsize=20)
        fig.subplots_adjust(top=2.3)

    plt.imshow(wordcloud)
    plt.show()

show_wordcloud(data['Response'])
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work but is adding an extra output I'm not sure about:

```py
df.groupby('Person').apply(
    lambda x: show_wordcloud(x.Response.tolist(), title=f"Person {x.name}")
)
```

Comment: How would I knw which word cloud is which ? I meant.. can I add title for each wordcloud ?

Comment: Added title with the identifying number

Answer (score 0):

Run a for loop for the categories:

```
from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

stopwords = set(STOPWORDS)

for val in df.Person.unique():
    wordcloud = WordCloud(background_color ='white',stopwords = stopwords, max_words=100)
    wordcloud.generate(df. Response[(df.Response.notnull()) & (df.Person == val)].to_string())
    plt.imshow(wordcloud)
    plt.title(val)
    plt.axis("off")
    plt.show()
```